# Disable console messages in Flask server

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask server running in standalone mode (using `app.run()`). But, I don't want any messages in the console, like

```
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2013 10:52:22] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
...
```

How do I disable verbose mode?

Comment: @DemianBrecht The thing is, the logs are send to `stderr` but they are just logging each HTTP transaction, kinda irrelevant for me...

Answer (score 194):

You can set level of the Werkzeug logger to ERROR, in that case only errors are logged:

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
log.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Here is a fully working example tested on OSX, Python 2.7.5, Flask 0.10.0:

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

import logging
log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
log.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to stop HTTP logs going to stderr; It DOES stop the "starting" message (which clearly has the "werkzeug" module name in the log format".

Comment: Works for me. The request debug messages are supressed. Using Python 3.5.2, Flask 0.12 and Werkzeug 0.11.11

Comment: Also works using Python 3.6, Flask 0.12 and Werkzeug 0.11.15.

Comment: Used to work for me until I raised `abort(500)`, so don't expect this to be working in all cases. Generally, it works but it's a workaround that sometimes fails.

Comment: Unfortunately no longer fully works due to Flask using `click.secho`

Comment: Changing the level of logging shouldn't be the solution to avoid logging one particular request only.

Answer (score 23):

This solution provides you a way to get your own prints and stack traces but without information level logs from flask suck as `127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2013 10:52:22] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200`

```py
from flask import Flask
import logging

app = Flask(__name__)
log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
log.disabled = True
```

Comment: This works when running my server locally, but strangely on Heroku, it doesn't.

Answer (score 19):

None of the other answers worked correctly for me, but I found a solution based off [Peter's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888799/disable-console-messages-in-flask-server#comment90473839_18379764). Flask apparently no longer uses `logging` for logging, and has switched to the [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/) package. By overriding `click.echo` and `click.secho` I eliminated Flask's startup message from `app.run()`.

```
import logging

import click
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
log.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

def secho(text, file=None, nl=None, err=None, color=None, **styles):
    pass

def echo(text, file=None, nl=None, err=None, color=None, **styles):
    pass

click.echo = echo
click.secho = secho

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Between setting the logging level to `ERROR` and overriding the click methods with empty functions, all non-error log output should be prevented.

Answer (score 15):

To suppress `Serving Flask app ...`:

```
os.environ['WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN'] = 'true'
app.run()
```

Comment: This works for me, I used it when testing flask application (using nose2) this removes the clutter in the terminal. Thanks

Comment: this breaks werkzeug version 2.1.0: https://github.com/cs01/gdbgui/issues/425

Answer (score 14):

In case you are using WSGI server , please set the log to None

```
gevent_server = gevent.pywsgi.WSGIServer(("0.0.0.0", 8080), app, log=None)
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, and I use Flask with WSGIServer

Comment: Thanks!! This really worked. <3

Answer (score 11):

@Drewes solution works most of the time, but in some cases, I still tend to get werkzeug logs. If you really don't want to see any of them, I suggest you disabling it like that.

```
from flask import Flask
import logging

app = Flask(__name__)
log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
log.disabled = True
app.logger.disabled = True
```

For me it failed when `abort(500)` was raised.

Answer (score 10):

Late answer but I found a way to suppress EACH AND EVERY CONSOLE MESSAGE (including the ones displayed during an `abort(...)` error).

```
import os
import logging

logging.getLogger('werkzeug').disabled = True
os.environ['WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN'] = 'true'
```

This is basically a combination of the answers given by [Slava V](https://stackoverflow.com/users/37141/slava-v) and [Tom Wojcik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5833429/tom-wojcik)

Comment: This breaks werkzeug version 2.1.0 and newer. See https://github.com/cs01/gdbgui/issues/425 and https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/2368

Answer (score 8):

Another reason you may want to change the logging output is for tests, and redirect the server logs to a log file.

I couldn't get the suggestion above to work either, it looks like loggers are setup as part of the app starting. I was able to get it working by changing the log levels **after** starting the app:

```
... (in setUpClass)
server = Thread(target=lambda: app.run(host=hostname, port=port, threaded=True))
server.daemon = True
server.start()
wait_for_boot(hostname, port)  # curls a health check endpoint

log_names = ['werkzeug']
app_logs = map(lambda logname: logging.getLogger(logname), log_names)
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('log/app.test.log', 'w')

for app_log in app_logs:
    for hdlr in app_log.handlers[:]:  # remove all old handlers
        app_log.removeHandler(hdlr)

    app_log.addHandler(file_handler)
```

Unfortunately the `* Running on localhost:9151` and the first health check is still printed to standard out, but when running lots of tests it cleans up the output a ton.

"So why `log_names`?", you ask.  In my case there were some extra logs I needed to get rid of.  I was able to find which loggers to add to log_names via:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

import logging
print(logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict)
```

Side note: It would be nice if there was a flaskapp.getLogger() or something so this was more robust across versions.  Any ideas?

Some more key words: flask test log remove stdout output

thanks to:

- http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/621740/ and
- [How to change filehandle with Python logging on the fly with different classes and imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839554/how-to-change-filehandle-with-python-logging-on-the-fly-with-different-classes-a)

Answer (score 5):

I spent absolute ages trying to get rid of these response logs with all the different solutions, but as it turns out it wasn't Flask / Werkzeug but Gunicorn access logs dumped on stderr...

The solution was replacing the default access log handler with NullHandler by adding this block in the Gunicorn config file:

```py
logconfig_dict = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "handlers": {
        "console": {"class": "logging.StreamHandler", "level": "INFO"},
        "null": {"class": "logging.NullHandler"},
    },
    "loggers": {
        "gunicorn.error": {"level": "INFO", "propagate": False, "handlers": ["console"]},
        "gunicorn.access": {"level": "INFO", "propagate": False, "handlers": ["null"]},
    },
}
```

Comment: this was the only option that worked for me

Answer (score 5):

Somehow none of the above options, including `.disabled = True`, worked for me.

The following did the trick though:

```
logging.getLogger('werkzeug').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```

Using the latest versions as of November 2021 under Python 3.7.3:

```
pip3 list | grep -E "(connexion|Flask|Werkzeug)"
connexion2               2.10.0
Flask                    2.0.2
Werkzeug                 2.0.2
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's the answer to disable all logging, including on werkzeug version 2.1.0 and newer:

```
import flask.cli
flask.cli.show_server_banner = lambda *args: None

import logging
logging.getLogger("werkzeug").disabled = True
```

Comment: I saw your comment on https://gist.github.com/daryltucker/e40c59a267ea75db12b1 and was searching for you to give you a +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

My current workaround to silence Flask as of 2022-10.

It disables the logging and the startup banner:

```
class WSServer:

    ...

    @staticmethod
    def _disabled_server_banner(*args, **kwargs):
        """
        Mock for the show_server_banner method to suppress spam to stdout
        """
        pass

    def _run_server(self):
        """
        Winds-up the server.
        """
        # disable general logging
        log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug') 
        log.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
        # disable start-up banner
        from flask import cli
        if hasattr(cli, "show_server_banner"):
            cli.show_server_banner = self._disabled_server_banner
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I merged custom logs and flask logs so as to provide same log format.

[sample log message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXuhN.png)

For mote details: https://github.com/senthilkumarimuth/logging_for_python

Comment: Please provide the relevant portions of the linked sources here, to both improve searchability and protect against changes to the linked content.

Answer (score 0):

For me the culprit was actually `nginx`. Nothing of the above worked, but setting `access_log off;` in the `http` section of `nginx.conf` file did the trick. See the [nginx docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html?&_ga=2.214162078.82955774.1696851238-1482873095.1696428488#access_log) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

A **brute force** way to do it if you really don't want anything to log into the console beside print() statements is to `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.FATAL)`. This would disable all logs that are of status under fatal. It would not disable printing but yeah, just a thought :/

EDIT:
I realized it would be selfish of me not to put a link to the documentation I used :)
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial

Answer (score -3):

The first point: In according to official Flask documentation, you shouldn't run Flask application using app.run(). The best solution is using uwsgi, so you can disable default flask logs using command "--disable-logging"

For example:

`uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:8001 --disable-logging --protocol=http -w app:app`