# Configure module logger to flask app logger

Tags: python, flask

My flask application uses a module which gets a logger like this:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("XYZ")
...
logger.debug("stuff")
```

Without having to modify anything in the module, can I configure flask such that the module will get flask's app.logger when it makes the getLogger("XYZ") call?

Answer (score 5):

The Flask logger is accessible during a request or CLI command via [current_app](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/api/#flask.current_app).

Example usage:

```
from flask import current_app, Flask
app = Flask('HelloWorldApp')


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    current_app.logger.info('Hello World!')
    return "Hello World!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 4):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18379764/747872) solution worked to me:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
logger.debug('stuff')
```

The default Flask configuration seems to use the logger name `werkzeug`. Adding or changing handlers for this logger changes the way Flask logs.

PS.: Python 3.5, Flask 0.12.2

Answer (score 2):

If you want use your Flask apps logging instance that is already established then all you have to do is import the current app and give it a name for that module.

**init**.py

```py
from flask import Flask

my_app = Flask(__name__)
```

my_other_module.py where I want to use Flask app logger

```py
from flask import current_app as my_app

class myClass():
   def __init__(self):
       constructor stuff....

   def my_class_method(self):
      my_app.logger.info("log this message")
```

Comment: How would this work for `views.py` if `app.py` calls `views.py` for use with `add_url_rule`? It would be circular.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can configure it.

By default flask logger's name is your app name, but flask has setting [LOGGER_NAME](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/config/#builtin-configuration-values).

Comment: `LOGGER_NAME` became outdated with v1.0 (or at least it's not documented anymore). If i'm not mistaken, the name now solely depends on the name of the app.