# Stop Flask from logging Javascript AJAX requests

Tags: python, flask

I noticed when I was using AJAX requests to retrieve some stats, the Flask console was filling up with 
`127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2015 13:29:25] "GET /servers/id/1/_api HTTP/1.1" 200 -`
 
constantly. Is there a way to stop AJAX requests from being logged, or stop a certain URL from being logged?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888799/disable-console-messages-in-flask-server

Comment: Check into using [Logging Filters](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/logging.html#filter-objects). Attach a filter to the [Flask logger](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.logger) object.

Comment: Logging filters seem to only filter out all of the connection messages, instead of doing a singular url

Comment: I wrote a thing to do filtering like this: https://github.com/nathancahill/Flask-Logging

Comment: ^ This actually does what I want. Thanks!