# Turn off stdout in Python Flask

Tags: python, flask

My flask code output to the console some data as below. And it includes some important customer information. I want to **turn off** all stdout from Python/Flask. Is there a way to do it?

```
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Jan/2018 12:53:30] "GET /index?search_term=term HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Jan/2018 12:53:32] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Jan/2018 12:53:32] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404
```

@sam-chats When I tried to use > /dev/null nothing has  changed

```
python3 main.py 
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:9876/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Jan/2018 13:11:52] "GET /index HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Jan/2018 13:12:00] "GET /index?search_term=python HTTP/1.1" 200 -

python3 main.py  > /dev/null
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:9876/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Jan/2018 13:12:23] "GET /index?search_term=python HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Jan/2018 13:12:28] "GET /index?search_term=sssss HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18379764 maybe this is what you're looking for

Comment: It's actually Werkzeug that is doing this behind the scenes.  Aditya had a good recommendation, though it doesn't really remove all the output--only to limit it to errors.  The other choice is to remove all the handlers and stop propagation to the root handler for Werkzeug, or simply setup a logging configuration that drops data on the floor if you don't want logging at all (I don't recommend this, logging is really valuable to have).

Answer (score 0):

When you start your server program, say `main.py`, do `python main.py > /dev/null`

Comment: I tried in the beginning. it doesn't work.

Comment: @ersinakyuz What happens when you do that? Does something happen different from the original command?

Comment: @ersinakyuz Please add that as an edit to your answer with proper formatting, it’s difficult to assess it in the comments.

Comment: I've edited in the question