# Disable request logging to console in flask

Tags: python, logging, flask

I tried everything in here: [Disable console messages in Flask server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888799/disable-console-messages-in-flask-server)
but the only thing I was able to do it disable the *starting server thing.

I found what seems like its functions in the werkzeug module in the `Serving.py`:

```
def log_request(self, code='-', size='-'):
    msg = self.requestline
    code = str(code)

    if termcolor:
        color = termcolor.colored

        if code[0] == '1':    # 1xx - Informational
            msg = color(msg, attrs=['bold'])
        elif code[0] == '2':    # 2xx - Success
            msg = color(msg, color='white')
        elif code == '304':   # 304 - Resource Not Modified
            msg = color(msg, color='cyan')
        elif code[0] == '3':  # 3xx - Redirection
            msg = color(msg, color='green')
        elif code == '404':   # 404 - Resource Not Found
            msg = color(msg, color='yellow')
        elif code[0] == '4':  # 4xx - Client Error
            msg = color(msg, color='red', attrs=['bold'])
        else:                 # 5xx, or any other response
            msg = color(msg, color='magenta', attrs=['bold'])

    self.log('info', '"%s" %s %s', msg, code, size)


def log(self, type, message, *args):
    _log(type, '%s - - [%s] %s\n' % (self.address_string(),
                                     self.log_date_time_string(),
                                     message % args))
```

But even when putting `pass` in all these functions instead of the code, it printed them to the console. I'm really clueless. Does anyone have a working solution for this?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I'm trying to monitor site activity using the console in real time, and it just spams it. Even if disabling it is stupid, why can't one disable it?

Comment: Well, if you were to host on a proper production server you wouldn't get any logs. It is, after all, a development server

Comment: _But even when putting pass [...] it printed them to the console_ How do you launch your flask app? Emptying those 2 func should totally disable the `127.0.0.1 - - [01/Dec/2018 00:00:00] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -` messages (even if it's not a correct way to do so, you should disable the `logging.getLogger('werkzeug')` logger), but your WSGI server or a web-server still may be emitting those messages.

Comment: As mentioned in the original post, I have tried to simply disable the logger but with no success. How I launch the app:

    `app = Flask(__name__)
    mysql = MySQL(app)
    socketio = SocketIO(app)
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        socketio.run(app , debug=debug, host=host, port=port)`

Comment: You mentioned you got no success disabling the logger, can you share what you're still seeing after you disabled the logger?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [01/Dec/2018 00:00:00] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 - messages

Answer (score 3):

```
import flask.cli    
flask.cli.show_server_banner = lambda *args: None

import logging
logging.getLogger("werkzeug").disabled = True
```