# How to remove Flask server messages

Tags: python, flask, logging, console

How can I remove **all** the messages from the console that flask logs.

[image]

For a quick note, I tried:

```py
import logging
log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
log.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
app.logger.disabled = True
log.disabled = True
```

But it only prevents the request logs not the server start.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable console messages in Flask server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888799/disable-console-messages-in-flask-server)

Comment: If you don't want to see that warning, you could *"Use a production WSGI server instead."*

Answer (score 4):

Here's a working sample:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

import logging
log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
log.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
app.logger.disabled = True
log.disabled = True

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

For me none of the answers worked. I am using Flask with gevent's WSGIServer, also using Nginx.
The access log were being generated by WSGIServer, to disable it use:
`WSGIServer(('', 5000), app, log=None)`

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
import logging    
logging.getLogger('werkzeug').disabled = True
```

But please do use a production server like `uwsgi` with something in front of it, like `nginx`.

Comment: `logging.getLogger('werkzeug').disabled` returns a boolean, it is hard to assign value to `False`