# Removing pyhon flask default console output

Tags: python, flask

Hi I'm new new at python flask and I want to remove the basic console messages after starting my python3 application.
I read a lot of logging but i did not found an awnser for my problem. I want a clear console after starting my application or my own logging messages there if it is possible. Is there any chance to remove these default output:

```
* Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
```

Comment: Why would you want to remove these?

Comment: I think that the reason you didn't find an answer is because you have no reason to delete it.

Comment: The users will start the application on their own and I want a clear console output for them.

Comment: Again I dont understand why you would want to remove them. Flask is a web application. Why would users be looking at the console or even running the application themselves?

Comment: anyway - these might help - disable console messages in flask 
 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888799/disable-console-messages-in-flask-server, Ability to disable Flasks internal logger - https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/1359, Really disable logger logging in Flask - https://gist.github.com/daryltucker/e40c59a267ea75db12b1 but these might disable all logging so you might be shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: It's the product owners desire, thanks for your help!