# using python logger to only log selected level

Tags: python, flask, logging

I am trying to only log to file issues of WARNING level or higher, yet the logger loggs everything.
My code:

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p',
                    filename='logfile.log',
                    encoding='utf-8', level=logging.WARNING)
```

- my logger:

```
flasklog = logging.getLogger('flasklog')
flasklog.setLevel('WARNING')
```

-the logging call:

```
flasklog.warning("FAILED LOGIN: %s from: %s", feedback, ip_address)
```

- I can see in the config that the level is set to WARNING, and yet an output looks like this:

```
03/01/2022 09:30:57 AM  * Restarting with stat
03/01/2022 09:30:57 AM  * Debugger is active!
03/01/2022 09:30:57 AM  * Debugger PIN: 110-508-916
03/01/2022 09:30:58 AM  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
03/01/2022 09:31:07 AM FAILED LOGIN: username doesn't exist from: 127.0.0.1
03/01/2022 09:31:07 AM 127.0.0.1 - - [01/Mar/2022 09:31:07] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 200 -
03/01/2022 09:31:08 AM 127.0.0.1 - - [01/Mar/2022 09:31:08] "[36mGET /static/style.css HTTP/1.1[0m" 304 -
03/01/2022 09:31:11 AM FAILED LOGIN: username doesn't exist from: 127.0.0.1
03/01/2022 09:31:11 AM 127.0.0.1 - - [01/Mar/2022 09:31:11] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 200 -
03/01/2022 09:31:11 AM 127.0.0.1 - - [01/Mar/2022 09:31:11] "[36mGET /static/style.css HTTP/1.1[0m" 304 -
```

Answer (score 1):

It is true, that you have configured your logger to have a WARNING level. But Flask has already configured its default logger and you are finding those log messages in your console.

If you want to disable that logging handle, you can remove it like

```
from flask.logging import default_handler
app.logger.removeHandler(default_handler)
```

where `app` is your Flask app object.

If you want to modify the flask logging configurations, you can refer the documentation available [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/logging/#basic-configuration) as of today.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm afraid that didn't change anything. I added  the lines you suggested and still received the same logging results. Possibly has something to do with the way my flask app is set up? ```app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="/static")```

Comment: what happens if you start the app without debug mode ?

Comment: no substantive change: the first few log lines aren't getting pushed, but all the flask stuff is

Comment: I suppose , you need to set the level to your root logger as well after your app is initialized like `logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.WARNING)`.

Comment: still no change, though maybe I have the order wrong? Here is how it looks now: ```app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="/static")
app.logger.removeHandler(default_handler)
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.WARNING)

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p',
                    filename='logfile.log',
                    encoding='utf-8', level=logging.WARNING)

flasklog = logging.getLogger('flasklog')
flasklog.setLevel('WARNING')```

Answer (score 1):

OK, turns out this was answered here: [Disable console messages in Flask server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888799/disable-console-messages-in-flask-server)

and the code that I needed was:

```
log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
log.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```