# flask socket io, hide /socket.io route calls

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I'm trying to develop an app that uses flask socket-io, but I find that these calls, when I don't want to see them, drown out console messages that I do want to see:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Mar/2022 15:57:12] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=N_NGFCx&b64=1&sid=MwzsB8-uko2MYx0wAAAY HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Mar/2022 15:57:12] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=N_NGFCw&b64=1&sid=MNZRlLHAp1c9ffXxAAAZ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Mar/2022 15:57:12] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=N_NGFCx.0&b64=1&sid=MwzsB8-uko2MYx0wAAAY HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Mar/2022 15:57:13] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=N_NG9NM&b64=1&sid=GwSAi2J8LzVR8y-HAAAE HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Mar/2022 15:57:13] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=N_NG9NL&b64=1&sid=x1_mrxzthX4lVxGHAAAF HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Mar/2022 15:57:13] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=N_NGFVA&b64=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Mar/2022 15:57:13] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=N_NGFVG&b64=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Mar/2022 15:57:13] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=N_NGFVN&b64=1&sid=xzqW67nd8jnBR2_aAAAd HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Mar/2022 15:57:13] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=N_NGFVO&b64=1&sid=xzqW67nd8jnBR2_aAAAd HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Mar/2022 15:57:13] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=N_NGFVP&b64=1&sid=fUoBKTV3-6j29UPwAAAc HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Mar/2022 15:57:13] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=N_NGFVP.0&b64=1&sid=fUoBKTV3-6j29UPwAAAc HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Mar/2022 15:57:14] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=N_NG9Z2&b64=1&sid=Im5sJRqD_FlhRK85AAAJ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Mar/2022 15:57:14] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=N_NG9Z0&b64=1&sid=bCMZekxmyORGCzscAAAI HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Mar/2022 15:57:25] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=N_NGCKM&b64=1&sid=I81WiYi8RkVmsbUsAAAN HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Additionally, I don't think I want these being added to my production server logs.

How can I circumstantially hide them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable console messages in Flask server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888799/disable-console-messages-in-flask-server)

Comment: @EgemenErtuğrul, no, I realized that its not a problem with the logging, its that the websocket is defaulting to longpolling and so THAT problem needs to be addressed and then the polling messages will disappear (since it isn't polling anymore)