# Disabling Flash 3.x logging messages

Tags: python, linux, flask, web, dashboard

Im getting ~15 of:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2024 12:10:13] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

in the terminal when Im running a Dash aplication. I think these messages are generated somewhere here:

```
server = flask.Flask(__name__)
app = dash.Dash(
    __name__,
    server=server,
    external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP],
    meta_tags=[
        {"name": "viewport", "content": "width=device-width, initial-scale=1"}
    ],
)
```

(https://github.com/AlexKurek/srt-py/blob/master/srt/dashboard/app.py#L53)

How do I silence them? I found a lot of methods, e.g. [Disable console messages in Flask server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888799/disable-console-messages-in-flask-server) but none of them worked for me. Maybe Im doing something wrong. Does somebody know what I should do and should I silence `server` or `app`?

I have Flask 3.0.2.

Comment: They look like Flask logging messages. See [Logging - Flask Documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/logging/) for configuration options.

Comment: @OldBoy I pasted the whole dictConfig: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/logging/#basic-configuration but I changed it to: 'level': 'CRITICAL'. The messages are still there. Also adding: app.logger.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL) and server.logger.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL) after line 62 (app.title) did not work.

Comment: frankly, I don't understand why you want to silence it. As for me it is only waste of time.

Comment: Silly question - after change, did you restart the flask app?

Comment: @tink Yes, after each try.