# Delaying output to a logging file

Tags: python, logging

I have a function that I want to output logging from. The logfiles are part of the program output as a record of when the function did what (i.e. not just debugging or post mortem stuff), so I want to store them in a specific location. That location is loaded from a config file, but I want to log success or failure in reading the config file!

So I can't create the logfile until after reading config but I don't want to read the config until after I can log the process.

Is there a way to postpone a set of log statements being written to file until later? A simplified version of the function is below: obviously it doesn't run because `logfile` isn't available until later.

It looks like `basicConfig(..., delay=True)` might be the answer but it sounds like that only handles a delay for the first logging event. Is there an answer for more logging events?

```py
import logging
import json

def record(config):

    logger = logging.getLogger(LOG)
    logging.basicConfig(filename=logfile, level=logging.INFO)
    logger.info('Start of continuous sampling')

    # Load the config file
    try:
        config = json.load(open(config_file))
        logfile = config['logfile']
        logger.info('Config file found')
    except IOError:
        logger.critical('Config file not found')
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: Please always proof read your typing, it is not easy to follow. The `delay` is like lazy loading, it will write when you do your first call to `info`, `warn,` ,`error` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple options, but here are two rather simple ones:

**Option 1**

Start logging into a temp file. If you were able to parse the config file,  copy the temp file content and [change the logging file handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839554/how-to-change-filehandle-with-python-logging-on-the-fly-with-different-classes-a). If there was an error, dump the temp file to stdout.

**Option 2**

Create a wrapper class that delays calls to the logger as long as the config file is not available. Something along the lines of

```
class MyLogger(object):
  def __init__(self, ...)
    self.logger = ... # temp file

  def info(self, msg):
    self.logger.info(msg)

  def changeLogfile(self, f):
    self.logger = ... # now writing to f
```

Once `config['logfile']` is available, call `mylogger.changeLogfile()` and continue logging.